# Optimization of data input

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I have an array whose elements I would like to increment when a new user votes.
For example if there are 10 options, from 1 to 10 and one user voted `i=3` it would be easy to write:

```
A[i] = A[i] + 1;
```

In the case where the options are from 'A' to 'I', how can I do this? Because I can't use the letter to point to a specific array element.

For a few thousand users, I don't want to do an embedded loop where I search all elements of the array to see to which one the choice 'i' corresponds to each time.

Can I do this in O(n) time?

Comment: You can convert the letter to a number then use it as an index.  How to do this depends on language. e.g. C would be `i=option-'A'`

Comment: please add a language tag or the language agnostic tag

Comment: @LoztInSpace thanks for the answer! the language would be python.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of a list. Then it's O(1) to increment (once - O(n) for n users)

Comment: Can you provide an example with input and output (see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is as simple as using dictionaries, a dictionary is like an array where instead of having index you have a key and for each key there is a value. For more information visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

So in your example just define a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0 .....}
```

then find the letter that you want to upvote and increase it:

```
data['A'] += 1
print(data['A'])
>>> {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
```

Even you can have dictionaries inside dictionaries, example:

```
data = {'A': {'Votes':0, 'Description': ''}, 'B': {'Votes':0, 'Description': ''}, 'C': {'Votes':0, 'Description': ''} .....}
data['A']['Votes'] += 1
```